# How to monitor FV Temperature online

Tags: fermentation-temperature, temperature-control

Is there a temperature monitor/device which I can attach to the fermentation vessel that will post temperature data back to a PC via Ethernet or wireless?

Comment: Can you remotely control your fermenter temp?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any, but if you like playing with electronics and programming, you could use an [Arduino](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9950) with an [Ethernet Shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9026), and an Off-the-shelf temperature sensor.   Doing that, you'd also need to set up a server process on your computer to listen for reports from your device, but there are tutorials for doing that sort of thing for just about every computer language out there.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this site yesterday using an [Arduino](http://www.elcojacobs.com/uberfridge/) like Baka suggested.

It's a little involved, and it would require you to beef up your coding skills, but the step by step guide gives quite a bit of detail. Also, this is a fermentation controller that also tracks and graphs temperature, so it might be possible to scale back the development.

There's also an [AMA](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/mkgek/i_programmed_a_fermentation_temperature/) on reddit with the designer.

Comment: The guy who did the site referenced above has now released an open source version of his temperature control system. Lots of details and instructions at http://brewpi.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't a programmer, then you can start building your system around a [BCS460](http://www.embeddedcontrolconcepts.com/).  I am running one, and it works like a charm.  Mine controls my HLT, BK, Mash, and Fermentation temperatures.  A little costly though if you only plan to use it for fermentation temperature, you can access it via your home network while you are at home or away.

Answer (score 0):

I read in Wireless something about [iGrill](http://www.igrillinc.com/). This is a bluetooth thermometer (designed for cooking) which hooks up to your iPhone/Pad. I couldn't see the point of it myself but it might be interesting to you.